# How to display the version number of an application in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, numbers, version, .net-assembly

I'm trying to find out how I will be able to display in a label the version number of my application, not that of the assembly, here 1.0.0.0?
But that of the application: 2.2.0.1
I am attaching a screenshot to you, acknowledging that I am not sure I did the right thing on the version number. Should I have left it as it was, i.e. also 1.0.0.0
Thanks in advance, Claude.

[image]

Comment: Did you see this class? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo?view=net-5.0

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve, it works, here is the code: Dim unused = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo (Path.Combine (My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "Prenommer.exe"))
Dim myFileVersionInfo As FileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo (My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\ Prenommer.exe")
Label4.Text = myFileVersionInfo.FileVersion

Comment: Don't post large code blocks in comments, especially unformatted. You should post your solution as an answer and, if you're able, accept it. That way, everyone knows that there's an answer to the question so they won't waste their time opening it to help or they will know to open it if they have the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solved it thus (extracted from your edit to the qustion; post answers as answers, do not post answers as question edits):

```
    Dim unused = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath, "Prenommer.exe"))
    Dim myFileVersionInfo As FileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\Prenommer.exe")

    Label4.Text = myFileVersionInfo.FileVersion
```

I wanted to point out your code seems redundant and can be simplified:

```
    Dim myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Application.ExecutablePath)
    Label4.Text = myFileVersionInfo.FileVersion
```

Please give your controls better names than "Label4". To rename a control, change the text in the `(Name)` entry of the property grid